# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25', though android-25 is actually installed

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have a Ubuntu Xenial VM running in OpenStack, there I've downloaded the latest Android SDK tools ( ***[tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip)*** ) from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html.  And everything is well configured:

- `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`
- `ANDROID_HOME=<ANDROID_SDK_PATH>`
- `PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}`
- `echo "sdk.dir=<ANDROID_SDK_PATH>" > <MY_ANDROID_PROJECT_PATH>/local.properties`

But when try to execute task: `./gradlew clean`, error occurs:

```
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 25".
Warning: Trying to install into ${ANDROID_HOME}/build-tools/25.0.0/ but package "Android SDK Tools 25.2.4" already exists at ${ANDROID_HOME}. It must be deleted or moved away before installing into a child directory.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 25".
Warning: Trying to install into ${ANDROID_HOME}/platforms/android-25/ but package "Android SDK Tools 25.2.4" already exists at ${ANDROID_HOME}. It must be deleted or moved away before installing into a child directory.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':demo'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Build-Tools 25, Android SDK Platform 25]
  Please install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
```

And actually as the error log mentions, I have the required tools installed.  Run `$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager --list` shows my installed packages:

```
Installed packages:
  Path                        | Version | Description                       | Location
  -------                     | ------- | -------                           | -------
  build-tools;25.0.0          | 25.0.0  | Android SDK Build-Tools 25        | build-tools/25.0.0/
  extras;android;m2repository | 41.0.0  | Android Support Repository, re... | extras/android/m2repository/
  platform-tools              | 25.0.2  | Android SDK Platform-Tools 25.0.2 | platform-tools/
  platforms;android-25        | 3       | Android SDK Platform 25, rev 3    | platforms/android-25/
  tools                       | 25.2.4  | Android SDK Tools 25.2.4          | tools/
```

What could be wrong here?  I'm a bit suspicious of the SDK path here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just confirmed my speculation - this is due to the new change made in the latest Android SDK release.

Thanks god we have a time machine, so that we can go back to see what exactly happened (can't really find any cue from [SDK Tools Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html)).

- [SDK download page on 2016.12.06](https://web.archive.org/web/20161206110755/https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and the SDK file:
  [android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz](https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz)
- [SDK download page on 2016.12.09](https://web.archive.org/web/20161209161958/https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and the SDK file: [tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip)

Let's have a look at the file structures of `ANDROID_HOME` before and after the change.

**Before**:

```
android-sdk-linux
├── SDK Readme.txt
├── add-ons (empty)
├── platforms (empty)
└── tools
    ├── a bunch of preloaded tools
    ├── ...
    └── ...
```

**After**:

```
tools
├── a bunch of preloaded tools
├── ...
└── ...
```

No more `add-ons` or `platforms`, only the `tools` as the new root directory.

**Problem**: Gradle will be confused if you set the `$ANDROID_HOME` directly to the unzipped top-most `tools` directory.

**Solution**: After unzip the new SDK file (you'll get a `tools` directory), create another directory (e.g. `android-sdk`), and move the `tools` directory completely inside the empty `android-sdk`, then set environment variables as:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/android-sdk
PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
```

In short: **DON'T** set `$ANDROID_HOME` directly to the new `tools` parent directory, wrap it inside another parent!

Comment: In other words, the latest update breaks things unless you manually perform some cleanup? That doesn't seem like a problem that will last long... and moving things will just make the next update more confused. Unfortunately, this also happens on Windows. :(

Comment: Yes, this file structure change they didn't mention in the release notes or so.  And when a user downloads the SDK and does a fresh setup (with the usual way of configuring `$ANDROID_HOME`), then it's messed up.  For other users who have SDK already, and by just performing an update, it won't break.  I have this problem just because of I have a docker image which downloads SDK when building it.

Comment: It is now may16, 2017, and as a new project is created, these same silly problems remains. Doesn't the kindergarten software team at Google read Stackoverflow like the rest of us?  What's the name of the programmer responsible? Platform: attempting A25 on win10 based system with all updates possible done. So stupid.

Comment: @carl  here is the ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37130500   And actually some Google staff marked the ticket as "Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)"

Comment: Yup this fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I just used **Invalidate catches / Restart** in my android studio. It worked for me.